# NodeJS send to POST also unchecked input

Tags: node.js, checkbox, ejs

I have a form in which I iterate an input checkbox field n times, as follows:

```
   <form class="" action="" method="post">
            <% availableDirezione.forEach((direzione, index) => { %>
                <p>
                    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkArray" id="check0" value="1">           
                    <span><%= direzione.usr_udf_direzione %> (<%= direzione.usr_udf_dirid %>) </span>
                </p>
            <% }) %>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mb-5">Add Mapping</button><br>
   </form>
```

I would like that in the post method, even the unchecked values are passed in the `checkArray` object.

Let's suppose the `forEach` iterates 5 times, and only the first and last checkbox are checked, I would like that the `checkArray` object is as following:

```
...
body : {
 checkArray : [1,0,0,0,1]
}
...
```

I tried adding the hidden checkbox with a 0 value. It fills the checkArray object 5 times but in wrong error. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but is not possible. This is not due to a Node.js limitation but rather a HTML standard. See second 'note' block in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox (under value section)

Hence you may try to fight against it with some front-end js code, but I wont suggest it. What you need to do is have a mean to reconstruct the array at the end like this:

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
  <% availableDirezione.forEach((direzione, index) => { %>
    <p>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkArray" id="check0" value="<%= index %>">           
      <span><%= direzione.usr_udf_direzione %> (<%= direzione.usr_udf_dirid %>) </span>
    </p>
  <% }) %>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mb-5">Add Mapping</button><br>
</form>
```

Then when you receive your POST:

```
availableDirezione.map((direzione, index) => checkArray.indexOf(index) !== -1 0 : 1)
```

This will produce a `[0, 1, 1, 0, 0 ... ]` array

```
availableDirezione.map((direzione, index) => checkArray.indexOf(index) !== -1 direzione : none)
```

Were this will produce a `[none, {direzione}, {direzione}, ... ]` array

The trick is to use `value` as your value media and set there something adequate. In this case i used the index of the value inside `availableDirezione` array, but you may even put set it to something even more meaningful like a unique id present in your `direzione` objects.

Comment: I'm trying to use the index as a value, but I receive a syntax error from the map function, is it missing  something?

Comment: You mean in the template building code? Which error are you getting?

Comment: Anyway that was the right way. I still didn't use the map function but I made it work rebuilding the array after passing the index as the value in the input form.

Comment: Yes, the map function has no much sense (from an information point of view) it is used just to rebuild an array as requested by you. Anyway, if you faced issues with the `value="<% index %>"` code, please inform me, so i can edit my answer. The code i posted is not tested.